# What does the electromagnetism vacuum wave functional look like?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, quantum-electrodynamics

The question is related to both [this question about the one photon wave functional](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/258383/what-does-a-one-photon-state-look-like-as-a-wave-functional), and [this one about the QED Hamiltonian](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81825/how-to-get-hamiltonian-of-qed-from-lagrangian).

What does the free electromagnetism vacuum state functional look like? My best guess based on the above links and [Weinberg's "The Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol. I"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/the-quantum-theory-of-fields/22986119910BF6A2EFE42684801A3BDF) sections 8.2 and 8.3 is
$$\Psi[A_\perp,\Pi_{||}] \propto \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \int \operatorname{d}^3k \left[\left(\delta_{ij} - \frac{k_ik_j}{k^2}\right)kA_i A_j\right]\right)\, \delta\left[i\frac{k_ik_j}{k^2}\Pi_j + \frac{k_i}{k^2}J^0\right],$$
where I've included the $J^0$ term for convenience in later usage where it may be minimally coupled to a matter field. The first factor is your standard Gaussian functional for a free field, and the second is a Dirac delta functional that quantum states tend to be when the Hamiltonian doesn't contain both canonically conjugate variables. Since $\Pi_i=-E_i$, the delta functional is equivalent to saying that the irrotational part of the electric field is fixed by the charge density, which is just the Gauss's law/Coulomb's law part of Maxwell's equations.

Comparing this to equation 2.16 from [Greensite's "Calculation of the Yang-Mills Vacuum Wave Functional" (1979)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1979NuPhB.158..469G) (which the paper cites as matching one from a textbook by [Wheeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Archibald_Wheeler)), it matches except for the extra Dirac delta functional (which, in the case of the paper, would have $J^0=0$).

In particular, **why is the constraint functional typically excluded?** In my mind, it's no different than if part of a Hamiltonian were free, $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, and with no dependence on $x$ the ground state just becomes a momentum eigenstate with $p=0$.